# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/TRANSIENT -- WildFly 17

Tags: deployment, wildfly, wildfly-17

I am trying to deploy web application to Wildfly application server but I was facing below error.
I am very new to WildFly. Can anyone help me on this.

I tried below two options both didn't worked for me.

1. Check your image to ensure that the server configuration (probably
   standalone.xml) contains the "iiop-openjdk" extension and subsystem.
   We do not expose the JDK's ORB; instead we have one that is bundled.
2. Add an Import-Package Statement to your Manifest.MF  Import-Package:
   org.omg.CORBA

   SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) Critical error during deployment: : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/TRANSIENT
           at com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WsnInitialContextFactory.java:187)
           at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:116)
           at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:101)
           at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
           at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:91)
           at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:43)
           at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
           at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
           at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
           at javax.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:192)
           at com.sun.faces.util.Util.getCdiBeanManager(Util.java:1552)
           at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Version.isJsf23(Version.java:57)
           at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.addELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:136)
           at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:221)
           at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplication.(WeldApplication.java:60)
           at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplicationFactory.getApplication(WeldApplicationFactory.java:52)
           at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:61)
           at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:109)
           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:39)
           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
           at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:458)
           at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:348)
           at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:200)
           at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:279)
           at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.lambda$verifyFactoriesExist$0(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
           at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor$$Lambda$726/14797740.accept(Unknown Source)
           at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
           at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:297)
           at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:211)
           at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:294)
           at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$$Lambda$725/29607565.accept(Unknown Source)
           at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
           at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
           at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:292)
           at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:205)
           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
           at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
           at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$720/9165134.call(Unknown Source)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$721/25627419.call(Unknown Source)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$721/25627419.call(Unknown Source)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$721/25627419.call(Unknown Source)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$721/25627419.call(Unknown Source)
           at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
           at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
           at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT from [Module "com.jars" from local module loader @100d6b1 (finder: local module finder @fd02e5 (roots: D:\KT\wildfly-17.0.0.Final\modules,D:\KT\wildfly-17.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
           ... 67 more

   ```
   13:58:17,948 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."nistevoGS.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."nistevoGS.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/TRANSIENT
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
       at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
       at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
       at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/TRANSIENT
       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
       ... 8 more
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/TRANSIENT
       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:283)
       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$720/9165134.call(Unknown Source)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$721/25627419.call(Unknown Source)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$721/25627419.call(Unknown Source)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$721/25627419.call(Unknown Source)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$721/25627419.call(Unknown Source)
       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
       ... 10 more
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/TRANSIENT
       at com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WsnInitialContextFactory.java:187)
       at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:116)
       at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:101)
       at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
       at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:91)
       at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:43)
       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
       at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
       at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:192)
       at com.sun.faces.util.Util.getCdiBeanManager(Util.java:1552)
       at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Version.isJsf23(Version.java:57)
       at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.addELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:136)
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:221)
       at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplication.<init>(WeldApplication.java:60)
       at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplicationFactory.getApplication(WeldApplicationFactory.java:52)
       at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:61)
       at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:109)
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:39)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
       at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:458)
       at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:348)
       at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:200)
       at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:279)
       at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.lambda$verifyFactoriesExist$0(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
       at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor$$Lambda$726/14797740.accept(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
       at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:297)
       at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:211)
       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:294)
       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$$Lambda$725/29607565.accept(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
       at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:292)
       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:205)
       ... 26 more
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT from [Module "com.jars" from local module loader @100d6b1 (finder: local module finder @fd02e5 (roots: D:\KT\wildfly-17.0.0.Final\modules,D:\KT\wildfly-17.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
       ... 67 more
   ```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  The CORBA stuff was removed a while ago.

Comment: I am using openjdk 8

Answer (score 1):

I assume your application was developed on Websphere and is not fully JEE compliant since you use the class `com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory`. First you should try to get rid of the Websphere specific classes.

If that is not possible you may try to add `javax.orb.api` as module (e.g. as global-module) to your server configuration. The class `org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT` is included in `modules/system/layers/base/javax/orb/api/main/openjdk*.jar` in WildFly. However, you may run into further problems when you fix the first.